# Appropriate database for web analytics?

Tags: database-recommendation

I am working on the web analytics it is similar to [google analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/),  Currently i am using the [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

#### Problem using MongoDB

Writing and reading is performed at the same time so after some point writing is bit slow. So i am looking for appropriate database which is suitable for following requirement.

### Requirements

1. Open Source
2. Can adapt large volume of data.
3. Better performance while aggregating the data.
4. Time based aggregation.
5. Real time processing.
6. Driver support for node.js and java.

#### Database should be scalable with node.js and java

```
 Saving the data using java.

 Fetching the data using node.js
```

Comment: unfortunately, questions for advice on which technology is "best" are off-topic for dba.se

Comment: @MaxVernon thanks for information. Technology or programming language used are node.js and java.

Comment: may be you should check the features of https://tempo-db.com/features/ not opensource though

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for DBs that are designed for analytics.
May be you should check these solutions:.

#### some data storage solutions specific to realtime analytics

1. [Druid](http://druid.io/blog/2011/04/30/introducing-druid.html)
2. [Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/)
3. [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
4. [Hbase](http://hbase.apache.org/)
5. [hypertable](http://hypertable.org/)
6. [accumulo](http://accumulo.apache.org/)

#### reference:

1. http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis
2. http://relistan.com/cassandra-vs-mongo/

Answer (score 1):

While I work for a competitor of MongoDB, FatDB, but given your requirements are Java, I would say:

- Cassandra
- Google BigTable (not sure of Node.js support)
- Cloudera (more of a Hadoop platform)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention the open source in the requirement.